# Node server on production must have node modules?

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

When deploying a node.js server on production, do we have to install node_modules or is there another best practice for third parties?

In the client we have a vendor.js file will all third partied but how we do it on the server? I don't want to install the large folder "nod_modules" bot to have a smaller file/folder to contain every thing.

What is best practice for deploying node on server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The node_modules is needed, it's part of your server code.
For production, you should install the dependencies with the `--production` flag, which will typically reduce the size significantly by eliminating any development dependencies.

```
npm install --production
```

Comment: This is what is best practice on the server because on the client its not best practice.